# Unable to insert these data from firebase to my 2d array using java script. The array only storing the last data I save in firebase

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push the data from **Firebase** to my `2D Array`:

[image]

Here is the data I am trying to insert to the `2D Array` :

[image]

Comment: Don't include pictures of text. Include the actual text instead. In the case of the JSON, you can easily get this by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Okay thanks. But what I need is the array to automatically add also new data from firebase when a user input new data. But thanks!